# Expression Languages Example in Apache Oozie

Tags: apache, el, oozie

I am currently learning to use Expression Languages(EL) in Apache Oozie workflow. Although I was able to get an abstract picture of using EL in Oozie, I was not able to relate the same with practical example.

It would be helpful if you could relate to real world example and provide explanation and provide detailed explanation on using EL in oozie.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Oozie documentation](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.5_Hadoop_EL_Functions) - there are some examples of using Hadoop EL functions.